# Why is this composite function entire?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function and let $z,w \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be fixed. Then, why is $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ with $g(\lambda) = f(z + \lambda w)$ is entire?
(By $f$ being entire, it means $f$ is holomorphic in each variable separately.)

Comment: Use a Cauchy formula wrt each variable to show that (assuming $f$ is locally bounded, eg continuous) $f$ is actually $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable, thus $g$ is, thus $g$ is entire.

Comment: @Mindlack Do you mean Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Since another answer mentioned Cauchy-Riemann equations, I was a bit confused. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Write $\lambda=s+it$ and $w=a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n$.

Since

$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}(\lambda)=\nabla_z f(z+\lambda w)\cdot(a_je_j)_j
$$
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(\lambda)=\nabla_z f(z+\lambda w)\cdot(ia_je_j)_j
$$
you get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline\lambda}(\lambda)
&=\frac12 \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}(\lambda)
+i\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(\lambda)\right)\\
&=\frac12 \nabla_z f(z+\lambda w)\cdot
\left((a_je_j)_j+
i(ia_je_j)_j\right)=0.
\end{align*}

---

Notice that
$$
\nabla f(\zeta)
=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial \zeta_j}(\zeta)d\zeta_j
+\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline\zeta_j}(\zeta)d\overline\zeta_j=\nabla_z f(\zeta)+\nabla_{\overline z}(\zeta),
$$
thus the full writing of $\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}(\lambda)$ for example is (here $\zeta$ is the variable in $\Bbb C^n$)
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial \zeta_j}(z+\lambda w)a_je_j
+\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline\zeta_j}(z+\lambda w)\overline a_je_j
$$
which makes no difference since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline\zeta_j}=0$ being $f$ holomorphic.

Comment: $w \in \mathbb{C}^n$. How can you take $\log$ on $w$?

Comment: @withgrace1040: "wlog" isn't a mathematical function here. It means "without loss of generality".

Comment: Hahaha! Sorry :) By the way, when $w = e_j$, it is easy. The difficult point of this question is when $w \neq e_j$.

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering how you can guarantee that $\nabla f$ exists. Do you use it as a total derivative as in the real case?

Comment: $\nabla f$ exists since $f$ is holomorphic, thus it is in particular real differentiable.